# Scala : zipWith[A,B,C](f: Function2[A,B,C], l1 :List[A], l2 :List[B]) : List[C] Method

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, functional-programming, fold

So i need to implement a function that takes two lists and a function. The function then  uses the elements of the two lists and applies the function on the elements and saves them into a list by using map and/or fold and the functions from the list class.

Example:

• `zipWith((x: Int, y: Int) => x + y, List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6))`
→ List(5, 7, 9)

• `zipWith((x:Int,y:Int) => x, List(1,2,3), List(4,5,6))`
→ List(1, 2, 3)

I do not know how to use the passed function and apply it on the two lists. My idea was to zip the two lists and then apply the function on every element of the zipped list.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have written for your idea ?

Comment: l1.zip(l2).map{ (A,B) => f(A,B) }  but i get type miss match errors  since i assume that i can't use f in this notation.

Comment: `zip` method returns a List of tuples, so you're missing pattern matching here:
l1.zip(l2).map{ case (a,b) => f(a,b) }

Comment: I need to solve this without using pattern matching and recursions.  But thanks this also works.

Comment: @Kiki If this is homework, you should mention it in the question.

Comment: @Jubobs sorry I am new here and this is my first post. Yes it is a homework assignment.

Comment: You can look at the [documentation for `Function2`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Function2) to see how you can use `f` without pattern matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elegant solution is using pattern matching:

```
def zipWith[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C, l1: List[A], l2: List[B]): List[C] = {
  l1.zip(l2).map { case (x1, x2) => f(x1, x2) }
}
```

To solve this without pattern matching, you'll just need to access the tuple's fields directly:

```
def zipWith[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C, l1: List[A], l2: List[B]): List[C] = {
  l1.zip(l2).map(tuple => f(tuple._1, tuple._2))
}
```

Comment: This is a homework question. Instead of dropping a full solution, you should gently guide the OP towards a solution...

Comment: I agree, however I "dropped" the solution before the OP mentioned this is a homework question...

Comment: I am really sorry for this,  it is my fault.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for a solution without pattern matching, I suggest the following one:

```
def zipWith[A, B, C](a: List[A], b: List[B])(f: (A, B) => C): List[C] = {
  a.zip(b).map { tuple =>
    f(tuple._1, tuple._2)
  }
}
```

By moving `f` to a separate arguments list, your invocations could be shortened significantly:

```
val a = List(1, 2, 3)
val b = List(4, 5, 6)

zipWith(a, b)(_ + _) // List(5, 7, 9)
zipWith(a, b)(_ * _) // List(4, 10, 18)
```