# Scala: map on zipped lists unclear

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, zip

For an assignment, I had to write a function

```
zipWith[A,B,C](f:Function2[A,B,C], l1:List[A], l2:List[B]) : List[C]
```

that takes two lists and a function and returns another list.
ex:

```
zipWith((x: Int, y: Int) => x + y, List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6))
    → List(5, 7, 9)
```

So I went at it and zipped l1 and l2 and tried to map the resulting list:

```
(l1 zip l2) map ((x:A, y:B) => f(x,y))
```

giving a "type mismatch: found: (A,B) => C, required: ((A,B)) => ?"

I researched for a bit and found two solution, but I don't understand why exactly this works:

```
(l1, l2).zipped map ((x:A, y:B)) => f(x,y))
```

I checked in REPL:

```
l1 zip l2 => List[(A, B)]
```

while

```
(l1, l2).zipped => scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped[A,List[A],B,List[B]]
```

which, in my eyes, doesn't look more like ((A,B)) than (A,B)?

Can somebody explain?

The other solution,

```
(l1 zip l2) map { case (x, y) => f(x, y) }
```

involves a concealed type of pattern matching (or so I understand) which I'm not supposed to use for the assignment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala : zipWith\[A,B,C\](f:Function2\[A,B,C\], l1:List\[A\], l2:List\[B\]) : List\[C\] Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333957/scala-zipwitha-b-cffunction2a-b-c-l1lista-l2listb-listc-met)

Comment: Indeed, this is a duplicate ... but this question is better phrased and posed in a more useful way than the other one IMO.

Comment: Now, if I were setting the assignment, I'd not allow `zip` either (looks very much to me like an assignment to implement a map-like function, not just `zip` and use `map`. What is your function supposed to do if the lists are of different lengths?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul There's no word on that behaviour. The assignment reads: Define the following functions non-recursive (without pattern matching and recursive calls) with map and/or fold. You can use any method of the class "List" but no own helper methods.


The other question is most likely indeed from one of my fellow students. Sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: @ClausRuepp, thanks fort the detail. I was just speculating/"guessing".

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul  Without `map` OR recursion,  it would be really ugly ... Not sure what would be the purpose of that as a scala assignment? Learn the power of `while` loops? :)

Comment: @Dima, yes which is why I didn't exclude recursion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List.zip` returns a list of tuples, so, when you `.map` it, it wants a function, that takes a single parameter of type `Tuple2`, not two separate arguments as you want it. If you cannot use pattern matching, you could deconstruct the tuple explicitly: `l1 zip l2 map { ab => f(ab._1, ab._2) }`.

Alternatively, as you have found out, you can use `(l1, l2).zipped`. This returns a special type `Tuple2Zipped`, rather than just a collection as in the other case. This special type has a member method `map`, that takes a function expecting two parameters, which is just what you need. This is why it works.

Comment: Thanks, this cleared it up. Why exactly is it, that the Tuple2Zipped is represented as T2Z[A,List[A],B,List[B]] but acts more like I would expect a Tuple2 (A, B) to act?

Comment: Because your expectations are wrong :) Tuple2 doesn't  have any `map` function at all.

Comment: You could also write `l1 zip l2 map f.tupled`.